# How to get the Template Chooser/Document Browser view on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, ios4, ios

What is the view used to create the Template Chooser view in the iWork apps on iPad?
[image]

How can I create a view like that on iPad, and what would be a best way to implement it on iPhone considering screen size constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built-in view that will provide that functionality. Which means there will be quite some work to duplicate that functionality.

What you can try is:

1) Create a new `UIViewController` with a nib.

2) Add the top bar and an `UIScrollView` with opaque = NO and alpha = 0.

3) If you have a fixed number of "templates" they can be added directly in the nib. You should be able to use `UIImageView`

4) Otherwise you can add the "templates" dynamically in e.g. `viewDidLoad`. The only part which can be a little bit tricky is calculating the frame. The following pseudo code should get you started.

```
int MARGIN = 20;
float templateWidth = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width / 3;
float templateHeight = 300;

for (int i = 0; i < [templates count]; i++) {
  int row = i / 3;
  int col = i % 3;

  float x = MARGIN + col * templateWidth;
  float y = MARGIN + row * templateHeight;
  CGRect templateFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width - 2 * MARGIN, height - 2 * MARGIN);

  // initialize `UIImageView` or similar

  templateView.frame = templateFrame;
  [self.scrollView addSubView:templateView];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.width, /* max bottom of templates */);
}
```

After you have got the layout perfected the rest should be quite straightforward since you only need to respond to taps on your template images. Take a look at `UITapGestureRecognizer` for one way of doing that.

Regarding the iPhone. I would probably do it in the way you select a document in the iWorks apps. Only one template is displayed on screen at the time and you swipe left/right to choose. But it all depends on the context. Perhaps a table view is better suited for the iPhone.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 6, use UICollectionView!